# In Varnish 4.0, is there any way to tell if a Purge request Hits or Misses?

Tags: varnish

Looking at the logs, I don't see any difference between a Purge HIT and a Purge MISS.  Neither are there any longer any apparent hooks for this in the VCL.  Is there a way to tell if Varnish 4 Purges hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only insight that I could gather was from `varnishstat`, and the variables `MAIN.n_purges` which is the total number of purge requests and `MAIN.n_obj_purged` which is the number of purged objects.

It's pretty clear that as of version 4.0.3, it's not possible to do it in the VCL.

Comment: Dittto for 4.1.0